# About responsive site content

Tags: html, css

So.. using Google Chrome function which allows me to see how your site will look on different devices. If i set a static size of px to a div for example, on a bigger screen size, how to make that div to expand on empty spaces ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want the div to be of 100px, add `min-width: 100px` in CSS.
Then you can add `width: 100%`, so that it will expand on screens bigger than 100px.

Answer (score 1):

Since responsive design is based around the concept of a sizeable viewport, you can help yourself a lot by using viewport units such as vw (viewport width) and vh (viewport height) more often. You will find that using these units instead of px will save you a lot of time and headaches when it comes to scaling. These units can be used for font-sizes as well, and they scale nicely.